# Set up own DBpedia server to create new mappings

Tags: frameworks, mapping, extract, dbpedia

I want to extend the mappings database of DBpedia. Therefore I want to run my own extraction framework instance on my computer. Although the latter is simply done I cannot figure how to feed the framework with newly created mappings.

What I found out so far:

- In "config.properties" I can define my own dump-folder.

  Some output directory can be defined as well. But what exactly is stored there?

  In "Configuration.scala" the url of a mappings page is defined. Does that mean that the framework expects a web page as input which will then be searched for mappings?

My goal is to define some mappings in a plain text file and then tell the extraction framework somehow to use this file as the source of all mappings.
If everything works smoothly I am going to contribute my results to the dbpedia team.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - Some output directory can be defined as well. But what exactly is stored there?

The extraction framework outputs N-Triples and N-Quads of all the extracted data, mapping-based and others (see also the files at http://dbpedia.org/Downloads).

> - In "Configuration.scala" the url of a mappings page is defined. Does that mean that the framework expects a web page as input which will then be searched for mappings?

The Mappings are loaded from http://mappings.dbpedia.org/ which is a wiki for creating and editing mappings. You can get an account and editor rights there and write your own mappings. They will then be loaded when you run the extraction framework (and the data using the mappings will be available in the next release).

> My goal is to define some mappings in a plain text file and then tell the extraction framework somehow to use this file as the source of all mappings. If everything works smoothly I am going to contribute my results to the dbpedia team.

You could go ahead and make the framework read the wiki code of mappings from local text files, but I think it would be better to edit them directly on the wiki. Your contribution will be instantly available.